# jQuery handling click of dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML that I'm inserting dynamically via jQuery

It is a bunch of <p> tags that I want to handle on click.

However the `.click` completely ignores these tags.

Here's an exmple of what I'm trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/cjds/tc2ty/1/

**UPDATE**

Okay the click is working but I still have a problem with the theory.

NOTE: The issue is that this data will come in after sometime because its fetched via AJAX. Also its likely to change.

So switching the order while correct in the example will not provide solution in the actual application. Any suggestions on how to set a click event for an element that's not yet present?

Comment: Read about "event delegation" and the `on` method: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few problems with your code. First, you're duplicating an element with the *same id*, and ids should unique. Then the problem you're experiencing is because you're not delegating the click event. When you create a new dynamic element the events that were previously set are not added to the new elements. There are a few ways to make this work.

You can cache the element and add the click event to it before appending it to the DOM:

```
var $p = $('<p class="reqImg">Random Data</p>').click(function(){ ... });
             --^-- a class not an id
```

Or you can attach the events with *delegation* by using the `on` method on the closest static parent, that is your wrapper in this case:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'p.reqImg', function(){ 
  console.log('Testing for click'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the knowledge and I'm going with delegation

Answer (score 1):

It's because the event is binded before the element even exists. You can try appending the `<p>` tag before binding the event.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding event hooks onto an object and then creating it.
Add the hooks after you make the object and it works.

```
$('#wrapper').html('<a id="reqImg">Random Data</p> ');

$('#reqImg').click(function(){
            alert('Testing for click');
});
```

​

Comment: But here's the problem. In my actual program this data is requested via AJAX and likely to change. So is there a workaround?